# Why am I getting TypeError "Image data cannot be converted to float"?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, matplotlib

When loading images in, I'm trying to make sure they are loaded in correctly by printing them out in pyplot, but I'm having problems. How do I load these images into Tensorflow and check them with pyplot's `imshow()` (or some other way)?

The image data is a one-channel(black and white) jpeg. It is initially loaded as a Tensor with an unknown shape and an uint8 dtype. I've tried making sure to reshape the Tensor into the correct shape and casting to float32. I've also tried making sure the values scaled from 0.0 - 1.0 as a float and using the Grey cmapping within the `imshow()` function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def load_and_preprocess_jpeg(imagepath):
    img = tf.read_file(imagepath)
    img_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img)
    img_tensor.set_shape([792,1224,1])
    img_tensor = tf.reshape(img_tensor, [792,1224])
    img_tensor = tf.cast(img_tensor, tf.float32, name='ImageCast')
    #img_tensor /= 255.0 #Tried with and without
    return img_tensor

def read_data(all_filenames):
    path_Dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_filenames)
    image_Dataset = path_Dataset.map(load_and_preprocess_jpeg)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    temp_DS = image_Dataset.take(4)
    itera = temp_DS.make_one_shot_iterator()
    for n in range(4):
        image = itera.get_next()
        plt.subplot(2,2,n+1)
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
```

My stack trace:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
line 34, in read_data
  plt.imshow(image)
matplotlib\pyplot.py, line 3205, in imshow
  **kwargs)
matplotlib\__init__.py, line 1855, in inner
  return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
matplotlib\axes\_axes.py, line 5487, in imshow
  im.set_data(X)
matplotlib\image.py, line 649, in set_data
  raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
```

Comment: Try calling `.imshow()` at different points within `load_and_preprocess_jpeg`, to see where things fall apart. Definitely verify that it works immediately before the `return` statement. If so, then something happened to it during the `temp_DS` journey.

Comment: I don't think `.imshow()` works at any point in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to plot tensors. In order to plot images, you have to run the session first. Try the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def load_and_preprocess_jpeg(imagepath):
    img = tf.read_file(imagepath)
    img_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img)
    img_tensor = tf.image.resize_images(img_tensor, [img_size,img_size])
    img_tensor = tf.cast(img_tensor, tf.float32, name='ImageCast')
    img_tensor /= 255.0 
    return img_tensor

path_Dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_filenames)
image_Dataset = path_Dataset.map(load_and_preprocess_jpeg)
temp_DS = image_Dataset.take(4)
itera = temp_DS.make_one_shot_iterator()
image = itera.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    while True:
        try:
            image_to_plot = sess.run(image)
            plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
            plt.subplot(2,2,n+1)
            plt.imshow(image_to_plot)
            plt.grid(False)
            plt.xticks([])
            plt.yticks([])

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```